# How do you find an analytical solution from a graph?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Given is a graph with three functions, g(x), G(x) and g'(x).

[image]

I don't need simply the answer. I want to know how to do it, or at least how to begin.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin 2x$ is the obvious one (red). Start working from there.

Comment: $x_0$ local max/min of $f\implies f'(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: And $G' = g$, I suppose.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8rdiy89sjy

Answer (score 2):

**Starting with the red graph:**

This is obviously a sine wave. A sine wave is
$$A\sin(\omega x+\varphi),$$
where $A$ is the amplitude, $f$ the angular frequency and $\varphi$ the phase. We can easily see that $A=1$ and $\varphi=0$. The angular frequency is defined as $\frac{2\pi}{T}$, where $T$ is the lenght of a period, which in this case is $\pi$.
So the red wave is the graph of
$$\sin(2x).$$

**Continuing with the blue graph**

First calculate the antiderivative of $\sin(2x)$. It is $-\cos(2x)/2+C_1$. At $x=0$ the function,with $C_1=0$, is $-1/2$. To bring it up to $y=0$ set $C=1/2$.

**Finishing with the green graph**

Calculate the antiderivative again. This yealds $x/2-\sin(2x)/4+C_2$. At $x=0$ this function is equal to the green graph if $C_2=0$.

**Conclusion**

We have
$$g'(x)=\sin(2x), \quad g(x) = -\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}+\frac{1}{2},\quad G(x) = \frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}.$$

Comment: No, they match up. $g'(x) =\sin 2x$; $g(x)=-0.5\cos(2x)+0.5$; ...etc.

Comment: @Carlevaro99 Edited it.